# Need guidance on tracking path of incoming HTTP requests

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a WordPress (version 4.5.2) blog (served by Apache) on Google Cloud Platform instance which is completely firewalled from the internet using GCP's Networking settings. Only connections from my other machine in the same GCP network (which is internet-facing proxy, nginx version 1.10.0) are allowed on single port 80. Some time ago I found the WordPress machine under heavy load caused by frequent POST-requests to /xmlrpc.php which I assume is a common attack, so I've blocked access to it with .htaccess to win some time. 
Now the apache's logs are flooded with

```
<same external ip> - - [timestamp] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 403 <same answer length>
```

as expected. The strange thing is there is not a single record in the logs of nginx mentioning xmlrpc.php, neither before blocking it nor after, though valid requests for blog pages and the rest are logged normally.
I can think of two explanations for this situation, but both are hardly believable:

1. The attacker (I'm pretty sure it's an intentional attack) exploits some vulnerability in nginx allowing the requests to avoid being logged.
2. The attacker managed to bypass GCP firewall, which is even harder to believe.

Maybe there's some way of tracking the origin of the TCP packets (is it my load-balancer or external address)? Or maybe I'm too paranoid and there's simpler explanation for the situation.

**Update**
I've eliminated option (1) by completely disabling proxying on nginx, so the least likely explanation remains the only one. Would be great if someone proves me wrong.

**Update 2**
After several hours the attack has stopped as it was not serving its purpose anymore (apache just responded with 403). I suppose if this happens again possible solution would be to use `tcpdump` to dump the communications and then analyze it, using Wireshark, to figure out at least the last hop origin. Still it would be great if someone more experienced shares some knowledge how to do that or points me in the right direction.

Comment: If <same external ip> is not your nginx system then you are not as well firewalled as you think.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm feeling like. It's for sure not ip of nginx instance. And at least basic testing (testing for open porst with https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap) proves that google's firewall does work in general (whew).

Comment: 1) You may post your GCE firewall rules here so we can take a look at it. 2) If all external traffic to your WordPress should be coming from the Nginx proxy, then you can remove the external IP address of your WP VM and pass traffic to it through its internal IP address.

Comment: It was a firewall misconfiguration issue. Some default rules that allow incoming HTTP/HTTPS are created by GCE, which I was aware of. What I've missed is that tags like 'http(s)-server' were also added by default for the WordPress instance. I've removed those auto-generated tags and learned the lesson. I suppose open ports were not detected earlier by the scanner (from my comment above) simply because apache has been unresponsive for that moment.